# Navigation bar not displaying page title in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have been unable to get a simple test working to display a title in the Navigation bar of my Xamarin forms app. I am providing my code below, basically when I set the title on the content page and wrap the content page in a navigation page, the navigation bar is not displaying the corresponding title from the content page.

**App.cs**

```
public partial class App : Application
    {
        public App()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new Presentation.Views.SettingsDeviceUnitView());
        }
    }
```

**ContentPage.cs**

```
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class SettingsDeviceUnitView : ContentPage
    {
        public SettingsDeviceUnitView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
```

**ContentPage.xaml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:GFIApp.Presentation.Controls"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="TestApp.Presentation.Views.SettingsDeviceUnitView"
             BackgroundColor="{StaticResource Key=ColorPrimary}"
             Title="TestTitle">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <Grid>
        </Grid>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Yet I see nothing in the navigation bar

[image: No title in navigation bar]

Has anyone seen this behavior before or have any suggestions? Thank you!

Comment: Did you test it on a real device?

Comment: No I have not, just on an emulator. I will try a Dev device tomorrow. Do you think it's an emulator issue? It seems to load everything else fine.

Comment: My guess is that the NavigationBar colour and the TextColor of your Title is the same if that makes sense Try using `BarTextColor` to change that and see if that works out for you

Comment: @Schwagmister It would be great if I could add this as the answer and you could mark that :D

Comment: It says I have to wait 2 days to mark my own answer D:

Answer (score 0):

Per FreakyAli's response I tested setting the navigation bar text color and I am now able to see the title. Thank you for the suggestion FreakyAli!

For reference, I added the following in my App.cs

```
NavigationPage nav = new NavigationPage(new Presentation.Views.SettingsDeviceUnitView());
nav.BarTextColor = Color.White;

Current.MainPage = nav;
```